# Automating MySQL migration from development to staging

Tags: mysql

I'm making an attempt to automate my migration process from development to staging without alot of unnecessary downtime/manual configuring. it's working "well" to a certain extent.

I'm using the `mysqldump` commands to grab the following:

```
mysqldump --no-data -u root -p{password} {db} > createdump.sql
```

On the development server which creates a dump of the create tables queries. FTPing over to the remote server and using the following:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info -u root -p{password} {db} > data.sql
# Import the new table structure
mysql -u root -p{password} {db} < /root/tempdumps/createdump.sql

# Import the old staging/production data
mysql -u root -p{password} {db} < /root/tempdumps/data.sql
```

99% of the time, there will be no new data on the new structure & The overall idea is to only populate these new fields/tables when the need for it arises. However, i'm getting hit with an error when importing the old data. The insert column lists do not match up to the insert query being called. What would be the best approach to ignore these errors and continue inserting?

As the table adjustments will contain default values, so the column name is not an absolute must when importing the old data

Comment: What would you like to happen when developers add, remove or rename columns? This scenario cannot be handled with SQL dumps, you need migrations of some kind.

Comment: Adding columns is answered below, renaming columns and removing columns is the next step to tackle which I have a solution in mind already on how to approach those ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use `mysqldump --complete-insert` along with your other options, when you dump your `data.sql` file.

This will cause mysqldump to output INSERT statements that name the columns explicitly, like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

Thus when you import it, it will only try to set values in three columns, even if the table now has four columns after your latest alteration. The fourth column not mentioned in the INSERT will be set to the column's DEFAULT, or else NULL.

If you don't use the `--complete-insert` option, then mysqldump outputs a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

This causes problems if the table gains a fourth column because of your alteration.

This solution should account for the case of adding columns. It will not account for other cases, like dropping columns or renaming columns.

If you want a more robust solution, I'd recommend checking out [Skeema](https://www.skeema.io).

Comment: Hey, I was looking for something like Skeema for years. If it works as advertised, it's an awesome tool.

Comment: Will definitely be looking into Skeema at some point down the road, however this answers my question perfectly. Thank you